# Switch from MSSCCI Provider to TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, msscci

I have a solution which connects to TFS using MSSCCI Provider.
How can I switch to using it with TFS and cut MSSCCI as the middle man?

When I select TFS in Tools --> options --> Source Control --> Current source control, Im getting a message that the active solution will be closed. When I open it again, the solution is still controlled by MSSCCI, ignoring my selection.

Any advice will be welocomed.

Answer (score 0):

In general the MSSCCI Provider is for previous version of Visual Studio, it's not supported any more in Visual Studio 2017 without having `Team Explorer 2013` installed. See [Connect any version of Visual Studio to Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server](https://blog.jessehouwing.nl/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#tfs2015) for details.

So if you are using VS 2017, then you can uninstall the `MSSCCI Provider` and `Team Explorer 2013`. Then just make sure the `Team Explorer 2017` is installed with the VS2017 (You can install the standalone [Team Explorer installer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/) if not installed before. ). Then you can connect to TFS/VSTS with the Team Explorer directly.

Besides, this article for your reference, it may helps:[Switching between multiple Msscci providers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michalma/2006/03/01/switching-between-multiple-msscci-providers/)

Comment: @Tomer S Have you resolved the issue? is the answer helpful? any update?

Comment: I do not have MSSCCI Provider on my PC, so I could not remove it.
Notice my answer to the issue.

Comment: It seems that Jesse Houwing's blog (hope I got the name right) is a bit out of date as it recommends using less than TE2013 with the MSSCCI provider for 2013 for some things.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue in the following manner:

1. Remove MSSCCI:Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider from each project file.
2. Remove the GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution section from the sln file.
3. Open VS2017 and select TFS in Tools --> options --> Source Control --> Current source control.
4. Bind all projects in File --> Source Control --> Advanced --> Change Source Control.